# How can I disable the screen timeout on Samsung One UI (Android 9)?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-9, samsung-one-ui

How can I disable the screen timeout on Samsung One UI (Android 9)?

I've only found:

[image]

which only allows to increase the screen timeout, with a maximum of 10 minutes.

Comment: I don't want to copy answers of other users, so I just link to the question instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840954/how-do-i-keep-my-screen-unlocked-during-usb-debugging.
As you can see, there is a developer option to make the screen stay awake as long as the device is charging. I hope this helps.

Comment: @GiantTree thanks!